# c# ContextMenu Handler

Tags: c#, c++, handler, regasm, contextmenu

I've tried to use this code to develop my own context menu handler for my app: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ratingcolumn.aspx

However nothing happened. Then I tried just compiling that code, building dll and using

```
regasm pathToDLL /codebase
```

to register it, this is what I got as a reply

```
RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can ca
use your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on
the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed
assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
```

However the new File rating menu did not appear(tried rebooting windows, refreshing associations, menus, everything). Am I missing something? Do I register the DLL as I should?

Comment: Seems that you will got better answer if ask directly author of article.

Answer (score 1):

Some people reported that when you use RegAsm with unsigned assemblies, you get false negatives (type registered sucessfully, but the type wasn't actually registered successfully).

See this post:
[Regasm and Com Interop false negatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648972/regasm-and-com-interop-false-negatives)

I think the first step for you should be to sign your assembly and make 100% sure you registered it.
Then you should carefully check what types do you expose as COM objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried registering it and steps from that link - haven't worked. Is there anything needed to be refreshed after it has been registered? Anyway, is there a way to do that on client machine(from application with UAC privileges using the code)?